# How to write DKIM TXT DNS Record in GoDaddy?

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, dkim

[image]

I am trying to understand how I should write my DKIM key in GoDaddy.  What I wrote in the picture is my guess but I will then add my DKIM Key to sendmail and if I'm note sure this one is right I'll probably bang my head for hour in case of an error figuring out which is wrong.

This question is about the Host TXT Value part and brackets or selector conditions

let's say my domaine is `goomoo.co` and my DKIM key is `ABC` and I want one DKIM Key for the whole domain.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:

in `Host` you put selector._domainkey.example.com

in  TXT Value you put what you see in the picture without brackets

This is for a 1024 rsa key

[image]